# Mapa google rebenta quando faço push dos markers

Tags: javascript, google-maps, marker

A minha função para adicionar markers ao mapa é a seguinte:

```js
function setMarkers(map, locations) {
              var i
              for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++)
              {  
                  var loan = locations[i][0]
                  var lat = locations[i][1]
                  var long = locations[i][2]
                  var add =  locations[i][3]
                  var image = locations[i][4]

                  latlngset = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, long);

                  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({  
                      position: latlngset,
                      title: loan, 
                      icon: image, 
                      map: map  
                  });
                  var content = "<strong>Nome: </strong>" + loan +  '</br>' + "<strong>Morada: </strong>" + add     
                  var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow()

                  google.maps.event.addListener(marker,'click', (function(marker,content,infowindow){ 
                      return function() {
                          infowindow.setContent(content);
                          infowindow.open(map,marker);
                      };
                  })
                  (marker,content,infowindow)); 
              }
          }
```

Sendo que necessito de remover alguns Markers quando é clicado uma checbox, andei a pesquisar e mandam colocar o seguinte código:

```js
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({  
                      position: latlngset,
                      title: loan, 
                      icon: image, 
                      map: map  
                  });

                 gmarkers.push(marker);
```

sendo que `gmarkers = [];`

Mas no `gmarkers.push(marker);` o mapa rebenta. O que poderei estar a fazer mal?

Comment: Amigo, o que quis dizer com "o mapa rebenta"? Que erro dá? Aparece alguma coisa no console?

Comment: quando meto um alert antes da linha e depois da mesma, a que está antes despoleta o alert e a outra já não

Comment: olha no console. Faz assim, antes do gmarkers.push(marker) dá um console.log(marker) e olha no console do chrome para ver o que está aparecendo. Se tiver alguma dúvida abre sua aplicação no chrome a aperta ctrl+shift+i e vê na aba console

Comment: Fiz o que pediu e com o push obtive a seguinte linha _.Xd {__gm: Object, gm_accessors_: Object, position: _.L, gm_bindings_: Object, title: "Av. da Liberdade 245"…}  sem o push obtive todos os markers que tenho.

Comment: Mas não aparece nenhum erro no console?

Comment: @AndréVicente, não aparece erro nenhum, penso ser por ele "rebentar".